# Multiply all elements in 2D list with formula

Tags: python, list-comprehension

#### Problem

I'm trying to change this 2D list by multiplying all elements with a formula, so this:

```
lst = [[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)],
       [(0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1)],
       [(1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]]
```

using this formula

```
(1 / (math.pi * 40.5)) * math.e ** -((x ** 2 + y ** 2) / 40.5)
```

becomes this

```
[[-0.007480807217716918, -0.007667817778372781, -0.007480807217716918],
[-0.007667817778372781, 1.5, -0.007667817778372781], 
[-0.007480807217716918, -0.007667817778372781, -0.007480807217716918]]
```

#### What I tried:

```
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        x = j[0]
        y = j[1]
        if x == y == 0:
            newlst.append(1.5)
        else:
            formula = -(1 / (math.pi * 40.5)) * math.e ** -((x ** 2 + y ** 2) / 40.5)
            newlst.append(formula)

print(newlst)
```

Output:

```
[-0.007480807217716918, -0.007667817778372781, -0.007480807217716918, -0.007667817778372781, 1.5, -0.007667817778372781, -0.007480807217716918, -0.007667817778372781, -0.007480807217716918]
```

The issue is I've tried to solve using list comprehension but failed syntax every time. I also want it to return a 2D list like in lst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work if you want list comprehension

```
lst = [(1 / (math.pi * 40.5)) * math.e ** -((x ** 2 + y ** 2) / 40.5) for j in lst for (x,y) in j]
```

Using a for loop could look like this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(lst):
    for j, (x,y) in enumerate(row):
        if x == y == 0:
            val = 1.5
        else:
            val = (1 / (math.pi * 40.5)) * math.e ** -((x ** 2 + y ** 2) / 40.5)
        lst[i][j] = val
```

output:

```
[[0.007480807217716918, 0.007667817778372781, 0.007480807217716918],
 [0.007667817778372781, 1.5, 0.007667817778372781],
 [0.007480807217716918, 0.007667817778372781, 0.007480807217716918]]
```

Comment: Thanks! What about creating it on the form specificed, so just replacing all the values in lst with the new value? Meaning nested lists so the result becomes more in line with the question. Also I need to handle special case if x == y == 0, it should return 1.5 (see 5th element in output)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using map, it was designed for this:

```
lst = [[(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)],
       [(0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1)],
       [(1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]]
func = lambda x: -(1 / (math.pi * 40.5)) * math.e ** -((x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2) / 40.5)
newlst = [list(map(func, l)) for l in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: Lambda functions are very useful. Great example !

Answer (score 0):

Not getting exactly the result you imputed, but you can do it with this list comprehension:

```
[[(1 / (math.pi * 40.5)) * math.e ** -((x ** 2 + y ** 2) / 40.5) for x, y in sublst] for sublst in lst]
```